# Pass parameters to modal popup

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, parameter-passing

I would like to know if we can pass id and class of button as parameters to modal, so that I could  display dynamic data in my modal page.

Navbar.razor:

```
<li><button class ="firstButtonDialog" id="mm" @onclick="() => _modal.Open()">mm</button></li>
<li><button class ="secondButtonDialog" id="cm" @onclick="() => _modal.Open()">cm</button</li>
<li><button class ="thirdButtonDialog"  id="meter" @onclick="() =>_modal.Open()">meter</button></li>meter</button></li>


private Modal _modal { get; set; }
public string _min { get; set; }
public string _max { get; set; }

private void OnModalMin(string min)
{
    _min = min;  
}

private void OnModalMax(string max)
{
    _max = max;
}
```

'Title' and 'Measurement' need to be dynamic in modal page. I would like to use passed parameters to display dynamic data here.

Modal.razor:

```
    <h5 class="modal-title">firstButtonDialog</h5> //title need to be dynamic based on button clicked

    <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="Min">Enter Min</label>
            <input @bind="min" type="text" id="Min" name="Min">[mm]<br> // [mm] measurement need to be dynamic based on button clicked
            <label for="Max">Enter Max:</label>
            <input @bind="max" type="text" id="Max" name="Max">[mm]<br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Done()">Done</button>            
    </div>


@code {
private string min;
private string max;

public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
public string ModalClass = "";

[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnDoneCallback1 { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnDoneCallback2 { get; set; }


public void Open()
{
    ModalDisplay = "block;";
    ModalClass = "Show";
    ShowBackdrop = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}

public void Close()
{
    ModalDisplay = "none";
    ModalClass = "";
    ShowBackdrop = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}

public async Task Done()
{
    await InvokeAsync(() => OnDoneCallback1.InvokeAsync(min));
    await InvokeAsync(() => OnDoneCallback2.InvokeAsync(max));
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple answer to this question, or a longer more comprehensive one that demonstrates how to build a "basic" Modal Dialog framework.  This is the later.

You need to separate out the *Modal Dialog* from the *EditForm*.  You should be able to host any *Form* in a *Modal Dialog*.

First, define an `IModalDialog` interface so we can have more than one implementation of Modal Dialog - say a simple clean Css one or a Bootstrap one.

```cs
public interface IModalDialog
{
    public ModalRequest ModalRequest { get; }
    public bool IsActive { get; }
    public bool Display { get; }
    public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalRequest modalRequest) where TModal : IComponent;
    public Task<bool> SwitchAsync<TModal>(ModalRequest modalRequest) where TModal : IComponent;
    public void Update(ModalRequest? modalRequest);
    public void Dismiss();
    public void Close(ModalResult result);
}
```

We pass in a `ModalRequest`:

```cs
public record ModalRequest
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; init; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object? InData { get; init; } = null;
}
```

and get back out a `ModalResult`

```cs
public class ModalResult
{
    public ModalResultType ResultType { get; private set; } = ModalResultType.NoSet;
    public object? Data { get; set; } = null;

    public static ModalResult OK() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.OK };
    public static ModalResult Exit() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.Exit };
    public static ModalResult Cancel() => new ModalResult() { ResultType = ModalResultType.Cancel };
    public static ModalResult OK(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.OK };
    public static ModalResult Exit(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.Exit };
    public static ModalResult Cancel(object data) => new ModalResult() { Data = data, ResultType = ModalResultType.Cancel };

    public enum ModalResultType { NoSet, OK, Cancel, Exit }
}
```

Our basic implementation - *ModalDialog.razor*.  It operates in an *async* context using a `TaskCompletionSource`.  You open the dialog by calling `ShowAsync<TModal>` setting `TModal` to be the component you want hosted in the form and providing settings and data through a `ModalRequest` instance.  You then await the provide `Task` that is set to complete when you exit the form. We use `DynamicComponent` to create `TModal`.  Note that we cascade the Modal instance to the hosted component.

```cs
@implements IModalDialog

@if (this.Display)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="(IModalDialog)this">
        <div class="base-modal-background" @onclick="OnBackClick">
            <div class="base-modal-content" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                <DynamicComponent Type=this.ModalContentType Parameters=this.ModalRequest.Parameters />
            </div>
        </div>
    </CascadingValue>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool ExitOnBackGroundClick { get; set; } = false;

    public ModalRequest ModalRequest { get; private set; } = new ModalRequest();
    public object? InData { get; } = null;
    public bool Display { get; protected set; } = false;
    protected TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult> _ModalTask { get; set; } = new TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult>();
    protected Type? ModalContentType = null;

    public bool IsActive
        => this.ModalContentType is not null;

    public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalRequest modalRequest) where TModal : IComponent
    {
        this.ModalRequest = modalRequest;
        this.ModalContentType = typeof(TModal);
        this._ModalTask = new TaskCompletionSource<ModalResult>();
        this.Display = true;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        return this._ModalTask.Task;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SwitchAsync<TModal>(ModalRequest modalRequest) where TModal : IComponent
    {
        this.ModalRequest = modalRequest;
        this.ModalContentType = typeof(TModal);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        return true;
    }

    public void Update(ModalRequest? modalRequest = null)
    {
        this.ModalRequest = modalRequest ?? this.ModalRequest;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void OnBackClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ExitOnBackGroundClick)
            this.Close(ModalResult.Exit());
    }

    public async void Dismiss()
        => await this.Reset(ModalResult.Cancel());

    public async void Close(ModalResult result)
        => await this.Reset(result);

    private async Task Reset(ModalResult result)
    {
        _ = this._ModalTask.TrySetResult(ModalResult.Cancel());
        this.Display = false;
        this.ModalContentType = null;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

And it's component css - *ModalDialog.razor.css*

```css
div.base-modal-background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

div.base-modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #888;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Your data class:

```cs
public class MyData
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

And form - *MyForm.razor*.  This captures the cascaded `IModalDialog` and interacts with `IModalDialog` to get any provided data and close the dialog.

```cs
<div class="modal-title border-bottom border-secondary">
    <h5>@this.Title</h5>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <label class="form-label" for="Min">Enter Min [mm]</label>
    <input class="form-control" @bind=model.Min type="number">
    <label class="form-label" for="Max">Enter Max [mm]:</label>
    <input class="form-control" @bind=model.Max type="number">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Done()">Done</button>
</div>


@code {
    private MyData model = new MyData();
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = "I Need a Title!";
    [CascadingParameter] private IModalDialog? modalDialog { get; set; }

    private ModalRequest modalRequest 
        => modalDialog?.ModalRequest ?? new ModalRequest();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (modalDialog is null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("You must cascade a IModalDialog to use this Form");

        model = (MyData)(modalDialog?.ModalRequest.InData ?? new MyData());
    }

    private void Done()
        => modalDialog?.Close(ModalResult.OK(model));
}
```

And finally a demo page.  It hosts the `ModalDialog` component and interacts with it to open the dialog.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Modal Dialog Demo</PageTitle>

<div class="m-2 b-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=OpenDialog1>Edit Model 1</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    <strong>Model 1</strong> Min: @this.model1.Min Max: @this.model1.Max
</div>

<div class="m-2 b-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=OpenDialog2>Edit Model 2</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-dark">
    <strong>Model 2</strong> Min: @this.model2.Min Max: @this.model2.Max
</div>

<ModalDialog @ref=modalDialog ExitOnBackGroundClick=false />
@code {
    private MyData model1 = new MyData { Max = 20, Min = -10 };
    private MyData model2 = new MyData { Max = 50, Min = -50 };

    private IModalDialog? modalDialog;

    private async Task OpenDialog1()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Title", "Modal Form 1" } };
        var request = new ModalRequest { InData = this.model1, Parameters = parameters };
        if (this.modalDialog is not null)
            await modalDialog.ShowAsync<MyForm>(request);
            // This won't complete until the dialog closes and the Task is complete.
            // We can use any return data at this point 
            // and this component will render as part of the ComponentBase UI event handling code.
    }

    private async Task OpenDialog2()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Title", "Modal Form 2" } };
        var request = new ModalRequest { InData = this.model2 };
        if (this.modalDialog is not null)
            await modalDialog.ShowAsync<MyForm>(request);
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot of one of the dialogs:

[image]

The code will temporarily be here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO73617831

Comment: If it is not trouble, would you mind giving repo in Net5.0. Current code gives me error.  Visual studio 2019 still doesn't support net6.0. I am planning to use either net5.0 or .netcore 3.1 for my project. Thank you.

Comment: See the Repo for a Net5.0 version, I also changed it over to WASM.  I've had to revert `ModalDialog` a little because Net5.0 doesn't have a `DynamicComponent`.  Why not upgrade to VS 2022.  I don't think 19 will ever support Net6.0 and 7 is just round the corner.  There's a charge next time ;-)!

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Works great. I will definitely think about upgrading to VS 2022 :)