# Using a component inside a different component blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-component

I have the following component:

```
@if (ShowConfirmation)
{
    <div class="modal fade show d-block" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="mar_top modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@ConfirmationTitle</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close btn p-0" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                        @onclick="() => OnConfirmationChange(false)">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="btn-close">@*&times;*@</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ConfirmationMessage
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    @if (ShowConfirmationbutton)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"
                        @onclick="() => OnConfirmationShow(true)">
                            SHOW
                        </button>
                    }
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                        @onclick="() => OnConfirmationChange(false)">
                        CANCEL
                    </button>
                    @if (ShowConfirmationbutton)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                        @onclick="() => OnConfirmationChange(true)">
                            APPROVE
                        </button>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@code {
    [CascadingParameter] BlazoredModalInstance ModalInstance { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ConfirmationTitle { get; set; } = "Confirm Delete";

    [Parameter]
    public string ConfirmationMessage { get; set; } = "Are you sure you want to delete";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ConfirmationChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ConfirmationShow { get; set; }

    protected bool ShowConfirmation { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowConfirmationbutton { get; set; } = true;

    public void Show()
    {
        ShowConfirmation = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    protected async Task OnConfirmationChange(bool value)
    {
        ShowConfirmation = false;
        await ConfirmationChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
    protected async Task OnConfirmationShow(bool value)
    {
        ShowConfirmation = false;
        await ConfirmationShow.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

Im trying to call it from a different component.

Just like I do with the common Counter component that is provided by blazor..

I'd love if anybody can help me out with some test snippet, something very basic so I can just see and understand how things work because Ive tried multiple ways and none seem to be working, so its likely I am missing something with the logic.

thanks, and have a nice day.

Comment: This looks like modal dialog.  If so here's an answer that demonstrates how to build a a modal dialog framework - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621631/13065781

Comment: And another answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114783/13065781

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution and it is working this way ( incase anybody is interested, or will be in the future ) -->

```
<ConfirmationPrompt @ref="confirmationDialog" ConfirmationChanged="OnConfirmationChanged" ConfirmationShow="OnConfirmationShow" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowDialog">Show Confirmation Dialog</button>

<p>Confirmation result: @confirmationResult</p>

@code {
    private ConfirmationPrompt confirmationDialog;
    private string confirmationResult = "N/A";

    private void ShowDialog()
    {
        confirmationDialog.ShowWithCustomTitleAndMessage("Custom Title", "This is a custom message");
    }

    private void OnConfirmationChanged(bool value)
    {
        confirmationResult = value ? "Confirmed" : "Canceled";
    }

    private void OnConfirmationShow(bool value)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("SHOW button was clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Polite] This answer may mean something to you, but I don't think anyone else will figure it out.  You call a method called `ShowWithCustomTitleAndMessage` which doesn't exist in the code in your question.